# what is the differences between reverse and reverse_lazey methods in Django?

Tags: django, reverse, feed

I can't use reverse() method in a class to generate url

for example, reverse() doesn't work in generic views or Feed classes (reverse_lazy() should be used instead)

but I can use reverse() in functions. what is the differences ?

take a look at following:

```
class LatestPostFeed(Feed):
    title = 'My Django blog'
    # link = reverse_lazy('blog:index')
    description = 'New posts of my blog'

    def items(self):
        return models.Post.published.all()[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return truncatewords(item.body, 30)

    def link(self):
        return reverse('blog:index')
```

the link attribute above only works with reverse_lazy() method.
but the link function works with both reverse_lazy() and reverse() methods

Comment: I hope the [official doc of **`reverse_lazy(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) is itself self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks but I have already read it but I didn't understand  "It is useful for when you need to use a URL reversal before your project’s URLConf is loaded"

Comment: @FaridDarabi In which part do you have a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reverse** returns `string` and It's similar to the **url template tag** which use to convert namespaced url to real url pattern.

**reverse_lazy** returns `object` and It's a `reverse()` function’s **lazy version**. It’s prevent to occur error when URLConf is not loaded. Generally we use this function in case below:

- providing a reversed URL as the `url` attribute of a generic class-based view.
- providing a reversed URL to a decorator (such as the `login_url` argument for the `django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required()` decorator)
- providing a reversed URL as a default value for a parameter in a function’s signature.